# string replace function giving unexpected outputs

Tags: c++, string, replace, c++17

I was writing a code that would substitute some random 17 character strings into a single alphabet, and it's giving me weird tampered outputs. Basically, what I'm trying to do is this:

getting input from user, put it in the input variable, input goes through algorithm() function untouched, and then goes to the replace function and is replaced. It then the replaced string gets returned back through the original route to the main function, where it is displayed.

I've kept the arrays a string type because the const char* gave me a segmentation error.

```
std::string Subs[53]=
{
    "LQlMv]G5^^1kcm?fk",
    "7W^S;/vB(6%I|w[fl",
    "<w7>4f//Z55ZxK'z.",
    "_W5g(lu<pTu3^_A7n",
    "OfLm%8:EF}0V1?BSS",
    "|+E6t,AZ~XewXP17T",
    "L-nIbhm5<z:92~+,x",
    "L-nIbhm5<z:92~+,x",
    "9bC5f0q@qA(RKZ>|r",
    "9bC5f0q@qA(RKZ>|r",
    "k=5,ln(08IAl(gGAK",
    "|N,8]dGu)'^MaYpu[",
    "!&,Y*nz8C*,J}{+d]",
    "Us9%^%?n5!~e@@*+@",
    "zF8,1KV#¥]$k?|9R#",
    "0B4>=nioEjp>4rhgi",
    "EG@0[W9.N4i~E<f3x",
    "(0Pwkk&IPchJHs.7A",
    "7XgmQ6fW<|J+NY[m0",
    ".g4CwX/DU!!~!zbtZ",
    "+_U'qn_/9Fo|gT/!n",
    "=0s(mYh&F%y=MBS5(",
    "cg71(}bo+Q5P8F[T6",
    "lc|a\%5.9pOpooU+QR",
    "E_(3A:o+.]qL3MYA6",
    "H@O'X_RiVS@8l0bKD",
    "Y1gbGD`~8d>HSWN35",
    "LQlMv]G5^^1kcm?fk",
    "T4}gI;`BFVfhw=-sf",
    "6BHMA0IRix]/=(jht",
    "yS$=@Jdpp?P2k6SMQ",
    "t1~|kkh+>4d>}OQ`a",
    "2Y-\\CU\"944yBluWD5",
    "'M\\ZbIX5{`Xd;qi!o",
    "?N+RtVqj_r(C5@#0\"",
    "2;*Livh?V$X/8z@Md",
    ")IN|7FOs2l-mAM[d@",
    "(~f268J},xXrK'Rp'",
    "&r/qf9fFHnzV!RzH/",
    "}naDRH4p$NI2a).t,",
    "{8DM+7!.Mge|~fnO|",
    ")r[@nI0YDH>6cE38p",
    "(0Pwkk&IPchJHs.7A",
    ")r[@nI0YDH>6cE38p",
    "8M-=cQFQ,pPo7eu=p",
    "0PHw=/|(tZ1}FHm/'",
    "[su`'0Oybc.\"-/W5)",
    "1uHl[IC7Sr#NUJV;I",
    "8z8%,jK0CDOkJz8I?",
    "3Ao2yXDN%YzpE&Suy",
    "zNs`7E'e/$i8VqaUL",
    "bzHmA^K2>7`UZ?!AO",
};

std::string Alphabet[53] = 
{
    " ","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","r","w","x","y","z",
    "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",
};


std::string replace(std::string rep) {
    int len = sizeof(Subs)/sizeof(Subs[0]);
    std::stringstream ss1;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (rep.find(Subs[i]) != std::string::npos) {
            ss1 << Alphabet[i];
        }
    }
    std::string input = ss1.str();
    return input;
}

std::string algorithm(std::string input)
{
    //some other algorithms come here(not relative to this question)
    input = replace(input);
    return input;
}

int main(void){
    int ed;
    std::cin >> ed;

    if(ed == 1){
//different function(not relative to the question)
        }
    else if(ed == 0){
        std::string input;
        std::cin >> input;
        input = algorithm(input);
        std::cout << input << std::endl;
    }

    else{
        std::cout << "1 or 0" << std::endl;
        main();
    }

return 0;
}
```

example input: `9bC5f0q@qA(RKZ>|r|+E6t,AZ~XewXP17T!&,Y*nz8C*,J}{+d]!&,Y*nz8C*,J}{+d]0B4>=nioEjp>4rhgi`

expected output: `hello`

actual output: `|+E6t,AZ~XewXP17T9bC5f0q@qA(RKZ>|r9bC5f0q@qA(RKZ>|r!&,Y*nz8C*,J}{+d]0B4>=nioEjp>4rhgi`

Sorry it's become long.

Comment: Not answering the question. In c++, the `main` function can only be called at program startup and cannot be used anywhere in the program:
a) in particular, it cannot be called recursively
b) its address cannot be taken. [main_function page on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function)

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `Alphabet`. I guess you want `ss1 << Alphabet[i];`.

Comment: I think just `Alphabet[i]`, otherwise `i` indexes " " at an arbitrary character

Comment: I think that that was part of the problem, but not a complete solution. I have fixed that part of the code, and with the same input, the output has become ```ehiloZ```, where it should be ```hello```. I feel I've come close, but I think there is something wrong with the algorithm or the way the code is constructed. I'd love it if you could tell me what it is and how I can fix it. thanks.